# AngularJS controller not executing in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

I was trying to learn the most basic implementation of controllers and modules in AngularJS.

[Here is the code I have tried:](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/33gbdoey/)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h1>
    This is the most <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_controller'>basic angularJS controller</a> implementation
    </h1>
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{ firstName + " " + lastName }}

</div>
```

The output is not getting updated:

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select `No wrap - in <body>` in the dropdown menu in **Frameworks and extensions** tab, check the pic:

[image]

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/33gbdoey/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Just a small issue,

Angularjs script did not get referenced. Just change it to wrap it in head,

Here is the working [`JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/33gbdoey/5/)

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan - is it possible to load boostrap and angularJS simultaneously in jsFiddle? If yes, how?

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan. But how from the sidemenu?

Comment: On the side menu you will find a division named External Resources , there you can paste the Bootstrap url and use it

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96433/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-student).